# Ler a partir de uma linha pre definida no txt

Tags: c#, txt

estou fazendo um arquivo txt pra guardar algumas informações de um usuario root (usuario,senha,nome,cpf,email) em ordem, e eu gostaria de saber como faço para ler apenas a linha que eu gostaria, cpf ou email ou usuario.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A linha do CPF e Email é sempre a mesma?

Comment: sim, é sempre a mesma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma

```
string cpf = File.ReadAllLines(@"caminho\arquivo.txt")[3];
```

no caso é passado o índice da linha(3 porque os indicies começam em 0)

Outra alternativa é colocar todas as linhas em uma lista de `string` e depois pegar o elemento desejado

```
List<string> linhas = File.ReadAllLines(@"caminho\arquivo.txt").ToList();

string cpf = linhas.ElementAt(3);
```

Comment: Ótima resposta.